# How to use a telescope to find a specific celestial body?

Tags: newtonian-telescope, star-gazing

I am a beginner interested in astronomy. I bought a Celestron AstroMaster 130EQ telescope. It's a Newtonian Reflector and it's not computerised. I did manage to see the Moon in some magnifications but my real question is this:

Suppose I want to see Proxima Centauri and I know it's coordinates, like Right ascension is 14h 29m 43.0s and Declination is -62° 40' 46". Having three analogue dials on my telescope ([picture from the front](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6bk213cggel5x25/20140420_111105000_iOS.jpg)) ([zoomed in](https://www.dropbox.com/s/nrrgik4pa1ia3x8/20140420_111123000_iOS.jpg)), how do I adjust my telescope with the help of the dials with the coordinates so I can view them from my telescope?

If I am wrong that these are the dials I have to use to adjust my telescope to the coordinates then please explain how.

I hope this question will also be useful to other amateur astronomers. Thanks.

Comment: Search for "How to align an equatorial mount"
There are some excellent YouTube links which can help you.

It is in general the hardest part of skywatching and I am doubtful that a textual answer will capture the power of a YouTube video.

Refer this anyway:http://bushnell.com/getmedia/5a750638-428a-4cfe-9504-7874387a8d09/78-4502.pdf?ext=.pdf

Comment: Just a note: Proxima Centauri is not visible at all from the Northern hemisphere. You'd pretty much have to be near the Equator, or south of it, to observe Proxima.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set your equatorial axis to tilt to match your latitude eg if you were at 5 degrees North then the axis needs to tilt to 5 degrees. Then you need to find an object of known RA and declination (at my latitude I always used Polaris as it didn't move) and then set the setting circles (the dials) to those, then direct the telescope to the RA and declination you seek.